# Regular expression to grab value from parameter

Tags: regex

I need to write a regular expression to grab just the values from the articleid parameter. (ie. 2689615). I have a good start: `[0-9]` but just don't know where to go from there. Basically, I need something to grab values between `'articleid='` and `'">'`

```
   <strong>Name</strong>
    <li><a href="detail.aspx?articleid=2689615">Id 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="detail.aspx?articleid=2689723">Id 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="detail.aspx?articleid=2689831">Id 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="detail.aspx?articleid=2690137">Id 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="detail.aspx?articleid=2690713">Id 5</a></li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the language you're using, but `articleid=(\d+)` should do.

Answer (score 3):

Capture:

```
/articleid=([^\"]+)/
```

This captures everything between the equals and the double quote...

I always use:
http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you know the parameter name and the value is just numbers:, this should work:

```
   articleid=([0-9]+)
```